# How to set array union as function return type

Tags: typescript

I have function parameter that takes in array union such as: `(ClassA|ClassB)[]`.
How to return from a function, either `ClassA[]` or `ClassB[]`?

When I try to return type `(ClassA|ClassB)[]` I get the following error:

> Assigned expression type `(ClassA|ClassB)[]` is not assignable to type `ClassA[]`.

```js
classA: ClassA[];
classB: ClassB[];

this.classA = this.function(this.classA, classAObject);
this.classB = this.function(this.classB, classBObject);

function(array: (ClassA|ClassB)[], item: ClassA|ClassB): any {
   // some code...
   return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function overloading can get you the desired type signature:

```
class A {
  a() {}
}
class B {
  b() {}
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B();

const arrayOfA: A[] = [];
const arrayOfB: B[] = [];

function doSomething(array: A[], item: A): A[];
function doSomething(array: B[], item: B): B[];
function doSomething(array: A[] | B[],item: A | B): A[] | B[] {
  return array;
}

const resultOfA = doSomething(arrayOfA, a);
const resultOfB = doSomething(arrayOfB, b);
```

You can check that `resultOfA` is deduced to be of type `A[]`, and `resultOfB` of type `B[]`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
array: ClassA[]|ClassB[]
```

type it like that if it's either an array of ClassA OR an array of ClassB. not an array of items that may be ClassA or ClassB

Comment: Tried that before. If i do that it breaks all array functions inside function and still returns same error that assigned expression type is not assignable to ClassA[].

Above code works. 
I am wondering if i can specify return type instead of any for the function?

Comment: you need typeguards on everything to know which type you're working with

Comment: Ok, read up on typeguards and I understand what you mean. Is there a way to manipulate either array without checking for type?
What i would like to do is concat and splice either array without caring what type they are, and return specific type array (ClassA[] or ClassB[]) depending on what was given for parameter.

Comment: You might be able to change the parameters so that it’s one parameter with array and item as properties. And the item type is like {array:ClassA[],item:ClassA}|{array:ClassB,item:ClassB} so that youre guaranteeing they’re of the same type.